# Getting Django comments to be able to use bold and italic style

Tags: python, html, django, tinymce

So I'm trying to get rich text to work for the cheeserater program where I added a commenting system using the tinyMCE editor in the textarea. This is what it looks like:

```
<table><td align=left>
 {% get_comment_list for package as comment_list %}
 {% for comment in comment_list %}
  {{ comment.comment|safe }}<br>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The underline and text size works, but the bold and italic styles don't. For example, I underlined and bolded 'omg', bolded 'wtf', bolded and italicized 'lol'.

```
<p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">omg</span></strong><strong> wtf <em>lol</em></strong></p>
```

It displays as the 'omg' underlined, but 'wtf' and 'lol' has their format unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tags work fine here. Check that you don't have a stylesheet causing those tags to use an unadorned style.

Comment: I just realized that not all of tinyMCE's features work. Such as the odd symbols, smileys, and generally anything that pops up.

Now that I think about it, it still probably isn't the root of my errors.

Comment: Also, It seems like it's a autoescape issue that doesn't allow the pop-up functions to work. I'm not sure though. I'm keeping the stylesheet unchanged as it's not one that I made myself. I don't know how to make/edit stylesheets anyway. The cheeserater program is here: http://github.com/jacobian/cheeserater

Comment: I found reset.css to have something like this...

"{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var".

I don't know anything about CSS, but it looks like I'll have to read up on it a little.

Comment: Never mind. The lack of content in reset.css appears to do nothing at all.