# how to disappear html tags in django (safe tag not working properly)

Tags: html, django

I am making a blogging website like this
[image]

I want to remove these tags (`<p>` `<em>`) which are being displayed in these cards

**page-html (before adding `safe` tag)**:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card-deck">
{% for post in top_posts %}
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{post.title|truncatechars:14|safe}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text text-justify">{{post.content|truncatechars:190}}</p>
      <br>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{post.timeStamp|timesince}}</small></p>
      <div>
      <a href="/blog/{{post.slug}}" class="btn btn-primary">ReadMore</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

**page-html (after adding `safe` tag)**:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card-deck">
{% for post in top_posts %}
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{post.title|truncatechars:14|safe}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text text-justify">{{post.content|truncatechars:190|safe}}</p>
      <br>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{post.timeStamp|timesince}}</small></p>
      <div>
      <a href="/blog/{{post.slug}}" class="btn btn-primary">ReadMore</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

**how page looks:**
[image]

help me to remove these italics and display the text in the original cards style.
BTW I am using `ck editor` as my richtext editor

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170124/11475846

Comment: couldn't understand the answer, I want to display only the text in the card content section not the HTML tags, for this problem I am using the safe tag found in Django, though it is helping to remove those unwanted tags but at the same time it's changing the bootstrap property and CSS thereby changing the overall look of my website

Comment: Have you tried overriding the property causing Italic? Add a class, like so: `<p class="custom_class card-text text-justify">{{post.content|truncatechars:190|safe}}</p>` then in your CSS class add class with `.custom_class {font-style: normal !important;}`